# How should the createBrowserRouter and RouterProvider be use with application context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Any big application will have general context that might need the router to redirect user. Since the `RouterProvider` can only be use at the root level. How do you use it with application context.

For example I have an `ApiContext` that redirect to a 403 route/component if the user does not have the right to access the API.

How to I wrap this context in the `RouterProvider` without having to rerender it on each route change. In other word. How can I have parent context that use the router?

It's working fine if I use the `BrowserRouter`, but the only way to use any kind of prompt before unload in v6.8 is to use the data api and therefore the `createBrowserRouter` method.

The same goes with header navigation. I don't want my header to be in every route component and part of the routing. I want my header to be static and route component to be dynamic.

```
// Aplication Context
export const ApiContext = React.createContext({});

export const ApiProvider = memo((p: { children: React.ReactNode; }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string>()

  if (!token) {
    navigate('/403');
  }

  const value = useMemo(() => ({}), []);
  return (
    <ApiContext.Provider value={value}>
      {p.children}
    </ApiContext.Provider>
  );
});
```

```
// Index
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "403",
        element: <Login />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <ApiProvider>
    <Header />
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </ApiProvider>
);
```

Comment: Using the RRDv6.4+ Data APIs doesn't change how React works, you render React context providers and nav headers exactly the same as before RRD6.4. What exactly is the issue you are trying to resolve? Please [edit] the post to clarify any issues/problems and to include a [mcve] of the relevant code.

Comment: RouterProvider does not have any children properety so it cannot have any application context. Contratry to BrowserRouter which has a children property and can have multiple context has child before it receive any routes.

Comment: You render what you need on routes, just like you could with `BrowserRouter`, ***or*** you render them higher in the ReactTree outside the routing context provider. We can't address issues in code we can't see though, so please do try to provide a [mcve] for what you are working with and trying to accomplish.

Comment: In the example above navigate('/403') would not work since there is no router above. Same with any navigation in the Header.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not actually factual that the `RouterProvider` ***be*** the root node/element/component of the app, it just needs to be higher in the ReactTree than any rendered component needing to access the routing context it provides.

If you are rendering components that need access to the routing context provided by a router, e.g. `useNavigate`, etc, then they necessarily need to be rendered ***under*** the ReactTree created by the router provider, i.e. the router component.

Move the `ApiProvider` into the router on a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes). The `ApiProvider` component should now also render an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) for nested routes to render their `element` content into instead of a `children` prop.

The `ApiProvider` component should also not call `navigate` as an unintentional side-effect directly in the component body. Either move the `if (!token)` check and redirect into a `useEffect` hook ***or*** just render a redirect with the [`Navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) component.

Example:

Application Context

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export const ApiContext = React.createContext({});

export const ApiProvider = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string>("");

  const value = useMemo(() => ({}), []);

  if (!token) {
    return <Navigate to="/403" replace />;
  }

  return (
    <ApiContext.Provider value={value}>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
    </ApiContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Index

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <ApiProvider />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Root />,
        loader: rootLoader,
        children: [
          {
            path: "team",
            element: <Team />,
            loader: teamLoader,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. Obviously the if(token) was just to demonstrate. I did not know about outlet and could not figure it out. This is too much change for now. I will stick to v5 that has a functioning prompt until I have more time to implement v6.

Comment: @BenoitMeunier Yeah, when RRDv6 first came out it was also quite a "mind-bender"  for me. Had to unlearn a lot of ingrained RRD patterns and habits. FWIW RRDv6 is a vast improvement over the older versions, even with the bits and pieces that were lost or not carried over into v6.